# Cachedrowset, JDBC and SQL server 2008 insert image problem

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I'm trying to insert an image file (.png,200KB) into Sql sever (columb type varbinary(max)) via jdbc type 4 (microsoft jdbc 3.0), here is my code:

```
            crsi.moveToInsertRow();                
            crsi.updateInt(1, Integer.parseInt(txt_TargetID.getText()));
            crsi.updateBinaryStream(2, fis,f.length());
            crsi.updateString(3, txt_Name.getText());
            crsi.updateString(4, btng_Gender.getSelection().getActionCommand());
            crsi.updateString(5, dpk_Birthdate.getSelectedDateAsText());
            crsi.updateString(6, txt_IdenNo.getText());
            crsi.updateString(7, dpk_RecordDate.getSelectedDateAsText());
            crsi.insertRow();
            crsi.moveToCurrentRow();
            crsi.acceptChanges();
```

crsi is cachedrowsetimpl object,fis is Fileinputstream object
Every going right, the columns get inserted, except the image column remain NULL.
What going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've solved this question. I should have enabled FILESTREAM in SQL server , also must have a Filestream group database,in which must have rowguiid and uniqueindentifier column.

Furthermore i can't use cachedrowset to upload filestream but i must use preparestatement to upload filestream.(cachedrowset will cause sync conflict)